# Convince Kotlin compiler map has a key

Tags: kotlin

Is there a way to tell Kotlin compiler that we guarantee map contains a key?

In the example:

```
val dummyMap = mapOf (
    1 to 2,
    2 to 3
)

...

someByteArray[some index] = dummyMap[some value that can be only 1 or 2]
```

Compiler will complain that dummyMap return value can be `null`.

I'd like to communicate to compiler I know that key will always be found in the map so it doesn't expect nullable value.

Comment: No, you can't; there's no way to prove to the compiler that the key-value pairs specified in `mapOf` will be present in the returned `Map`. While contracts were recently added to the language, I do not believe they are powerful enough for this use case.

Comment: I was wondering that. Well I'll do the check for now. Thanks!

Comment: just use non-null cast in that case: `dummyMap[1]!!`

Comment: I'll use elvis operator for now. Thanks for suggestions @Pawel

Comment: I don't see how elvis operator helps since your `get` will never return null. On the contrary, it implies it's possible to get null and might cause confusion.

Comment: You're right, I've put it there since IntelliJ is complaining. 
It may help during development. The proper way would be to use !! operator as you've suggested.

Comment: I've usually done this by having an extension function `require()` that takes `T?` and returns a `T`, throwing a custom `IllegalArgumentException` or `AssertionError` etc. if the argument is indeed null. Then I can just do `map[something].require()`, and get a clearer exception if for whatever reason the value is indeed `null`. However, since you can reasonably guarantee that the value exists, the `!!` operator should be fine.

Comment: rather than the elvis operator, you can also  use the getOrDefault(i, defaultVal) method in maps https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-map/get-or-default.html

Answer (score 3):

Kotlin Collections already defines the [`Map.getValue()` extension function](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/get-value.html), which returns an element with non-nullable type or throws `NoSuchElementException`.

Now this will compile fine:

```
someByteArray[some index] = dummyMap.getValue(1)
```

Comment: My idea was to omit explicit checks, since I already know the key is always present.

Comment: I guess I don't understand what you mean by an "explicit check"... there's no `if` logic or `!!` etc.

Comment: There is in the extension function:
getOrElseNullable(key, { throw NoSuchElementException("Key $key is missing in the map.") })

What I'd like to achieve is to have unchecked retrieval of the value, since I know there's always going to be a value for the key. Does that make sense?

Comment: More often than not, things that ‘you know will always be true’ turn out to be false at some point — due to coding errors, unexpected input, future changes, or whatever.  In the long run, it's often better to handle them properly.